# findAll() method doesn't work when forceQuote is true in spring-data-cassandra

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I'm using spring-data-cassandra in my spring boot project. 
I use (forceQuote = true) because I have tables with uppercase letters. 
When I tried to execute findById() method, it worked without any problem, but findAll() method threw an exception. I tried to debug the application and I found that spring-data-cassandra adds extra quotes to the table name while executing the query. So, the table name becomes ""MyTable"".
The exception is `given string ["MyTable"] is not a valid quoted or unquoted identifier`.

Is that a bug in spring-data-cassandra?

```
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.PrimaryKey;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.Table;

@Table(value = "MyTable", forceQuote = true)
@Data
public class MyTable {

    @PrimaryKey
    private Integer key;

    //some attributes.
}
```

---

```
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.CassandraRepository;

public interface MyTableRepository extends CassandraRepository<MyTable, Integer> {
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Can you file a bug report at https://jira.spring.io/projects/DATACASS/issues/ along with the CQL to setup your table?